# Get matrix with colors of colomap figure

Tags: matlab

I have generated a heatmap from a matrix of values and applied a colormap on it. Is there a way for me to create an m-by-3 matrix of the colors of each square segment?

Comment: m-by-3 or m-by-n-by-3? Custom colour map or built in?

Answer (score 1):

My understanding is that you have a matrix of values (m-by-n) which you colour using a colour map and you want to get the 3D (m-by-n-by-3) matrix that is the RBG image of this coloured matrix. In that case try:

```
%//C is your data
C = randn(m,n);

%//d is the number of discrete colour in your colormap and map is your colormap itself.
d=4;
map = jet(d);

%//Normalize C to index map, i.e. make values of C range from 1 to d
C_norm = (C - min(C(:)))./(max(C(:)) - min(C(:)));  %//Normalize to btw [0,1]
C_discrete = ceil(C_norm*(d-1)+1);                  %//Normalize to btw [1,d]

%//Index in map using linearized (i.e. m*n-by-1 vector) version of C
C_mapped = map(C_discrete(:),:);

%//Reshape to m-by-n-by-3
C_RGBreshape(permute(C_mapped, [1, 3, 2]), m, n, 3);
```

Answer (score 0):

You mean to create a matrix with the colormap? Normally you do it the other way around. Try

```
cmap = jet(64);
colormap(cmap);
```

This assigns the colormap to `cmap` as a matrix and then assigns it to th axes. I also think that the colormap is an axes property and can be accessed through the `set` and `get` functions. Also you may not want to use the `jet` colormap but any colormap can of course be used